# File triggered CDF job

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

In CDAP, partition trigger type is available as below.

schedule(buildSchedule("runOnlyAtNight", ProgramType.WORKFLOW, "cleanupWorkflow")
.withTimeWindow("22:00", "06:00”).waitUntilMet()
.triggerOnPartitions("myDataset", 1));

Is it available in Cloud data fusion on GCP?

If yes, does 'myDataset' refer to a folder in a bucket? That would mean whenever there is a change (addition of a file {names will be different due to date suffix}), CDF will trigger the job.

If this is possible, there will not be dependency on Cloud function.

Comment: So you are searching for some option in Data Fusion which allows you to "listen" when some file was created on GCS and then execute the job?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not available in Data Fusion. Dataset is a concept in CDAP but not applicable in Data Fusion.